Python-telegram-bot not registering button press
my bot is not registering inline button presses. What should I do?
async def button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query
    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    await query.answer()
    if query.data == '1':
        keyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Что такое баллы, и для чего они нужны?",
                                  callback_data="7")],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Что делать, если у меня изменился номер мобильного телефона?",
                                  callback_data="8")],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Что делать, если терминал АЗС не распознает мою карту или выдает сообщение о том, что она заблокирована?",
                                  callback_data="9")],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Что делать, если по карте не накапливаются баллы?",
                                  callback_data="10")],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Что делать, если моя Карта повреждена или ее у меня украли?",
                                  callback_data="11")],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Сколько карт может одновременно использовать один участник?",
                                  callback_data="12")]
            ]

        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        await query.edit_message_text('Вопросы и ответы:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


        if query.data == '7':
            print(query.data)
            keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Домой", callback_data="100")]]
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            await query.edit_message_text('Балл - это единица, которая зачисляется на счет участника за покупки с картой Программы лояльности на АЗС «ЛУКОЙЛ» и дает возможность впоследствии приобрести товар на АЗС со скидкой. При списании: 1 балл = 1 рубль скидки.\nБаллы можно копить с момента получения карты. Никакой дополнительной активации не требуется, но необходима регистрация.', reply_markup=reply_markup)



        if query.data == '8':
            print(query.data)
            keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Домой", callback_data="100")]]
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            await query.edit_message_text('Позвоните в Службу поддержки клиентов ЛУКОЙЛ 8-800-1000-911 и сообщите об изменениях, чтобы своевременно получать актуальную информацию о Программе лояльности.', reply_markup=reply_markup)

    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    if query.data == '2':
        print('2')
        await query.edit_message_text('По всем вопросам обращайтесь по телефону нашей горячей линии 8(800)100-09-11 (Номер бесплатный для звонков по России')

I am expecting that the 'Что такое баллы, и для чего они нужны?' and 'Что делать, если у меня изменился номер мобильного телефона?' should work. But python isn't actually entering if query.data == '7': and if query.data == '8':. I appriciate for every answer.
Thank you
